# How can I add two TextFields Values?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have taken time from `UIDatePickerView` and placed each time in two textFields. Now I need to add the two textfield values.
for example:

```
NSString *inTm=@"11:12";
NSString *outTm=@"12:12";
NSDate *inTime=[timeFormate dateFromString:inTm];
NSDate *outTime=[timeFormate dateFromString:outTm];

fistTextField.text=inTm;
secondTextField.text=outTm;
totalTextField="?"
```

Now I need to add the two times. How can I show the sum of time in a third textField.
Plz help me..

Answer (score 0):

It hardly makes sense to add to dates. What makes sense is to add an interval (`NSTimeInterval`) to a date (`NSDate`) and that's what [`NSDate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has out of the box: :

```
- (id)dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Sample:

```
NSTimeInterval hour = 3600;
NSDate *now  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0];
NSDate *inOneHour = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:hour];
```

And the time interval between two `NSDate`s:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

Sample:

```
NSTimeInterval diff = [inOneHour timeIntervalSinceDate:now];
```